# Android Intent NullPointer Exception

Tags: android-intent, nullpointerexception, android-activity, android-manifest

i'm trying to call a different Activity, depending on if the Password entered was right or not. But I'm always receiving a NullPointerException which force closes my app.

**My Code:**

```
 Intent MainScreenIntent = new Intent("com.shr.khg.Login");
 startActivity(MainScreenIntent);
```

**My Manifest:**

```
<activity
            android:name="com.shr.khg.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login" >
             <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.shr.khg.Login" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

**The Log:**

```
04-01 20:05:59.221: D/dalvikvm(1846): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 34K, 4% free 8624K/8963K, paused 57ms
04-01 20:05:59.230: I/dalvikvm-heap(1846): Grow heap (frag case) to 9.514MB for 1024016-byte allocation
04-01 20:05:59.320: D/dalvikvm(1846): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 4% free 9624K/9991K, paused 58ms
04-01 20:05:59.460: D/dalvikvm(1846): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 4% free 9624K/9991K, paused 5ms+14ms
04-01 20:06:05.860: D/AndroidRuntime(1846): Shutting down VM
04-01 20:06:05.860: W/dalvikvm(1846): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40014760)
04-01 20:06:05.870: E/AndroidRuntime(1846): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-01 20:06:05.870: E/AndroidRuntime(1846): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.shr.khg/com.shr.khg.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-01 20:06:05.870: E/AndroidRuntime(1846):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1815)
04-01 20:06:05.870: E/AndroidRuntime(1846):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1831)
04-01 20:06:05.870: E/AndroidRuntime(1846):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:122)
04-01 20:06:05.870: E/AndroidRuntime(1846):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1024)
04-01 20:06:05.870: E/AndroidRuntime(1846):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-01 20:06:05.870: E/AndroidRuntime(1846):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
04-01 20:06:05.870: E/AndroidRuntime(1846):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
04-01 20:06:05.870: E/AndroidRuntime(1846):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-01 20:06:05.870: E/AndroidRuntime(1846):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
04-01 20:06:05.870: E/AndroidRuntime(1846):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
04-01 20:06:05.870: E/AndroidRuntime(1846):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
04-01 20:06:05.870: E/AndroidRuntime(1846):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-01 20:06:05.870: E/AndroidRuntime(1846): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-01 20:06:05.870: E/AndroidRuntime(1846):     at com.shr.khg.LoginActivity.setup(LoginActivity.java:98)
04-01 20:06:05.870: E/AndroidRuntime(1846):     at com.shr.khg.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:89)
04-01 20:06:05.870: E/AndroidRuntime(1846):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4397)
04-01 20:06:05.870: E/AndroidRuntime(1846):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
04-01 20:06:05.870: E/AndroidRuntime(1846):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1779)
04-01 20:06:05.870: E/AndroidRuntime(1846):     ... 11 more
```

What am I doing wrrong? I just dont understand it, since it looks like it works with all my other Activities, but just not with that one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the syntax for creating an intent to start a new activity say `ActivityB` from `ActivityA` is:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

You have got your syntax wrong. And the log shows NullPointerException at lines 98 and 89 of your `LoginActivity`. Please post the code from those two lines.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer now, I accidentely assigned the wrong layout to the activity, so that it couldnt set the handler.

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong in your the onCreate of the activity you're making. The problem is that your application attempts to use null in a case where an object is required.